# Add Result From Previous Year

Tags: mysql, datetime, sum

I have query result for show sum result from "2019", here's my query and result :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Number1 - Number2) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
    `myTable` 
WHERE 
    YEAR(Date) = '2019'
```

| total |
| --- |
| 136 |

And then i wanna add sum result from "2019" with sum result from January 2020, i already tried this query but the result not as i expected :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Number1 - Number2) AS TOTAL 
FROM 
    `myTable` 
WHERE 
    YEAR(Date) <= '2020' AND MONTH(DATE) <='1'
```

Result from query
|total|
|:----|
| 36  |

Expected result
|total|
|:----|
| 139 |

im using mysql 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an inequality directly with the date column here:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Number1 - Number2) AS TOTAL 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Date >= '2019-01-01' AND Date < '2020-02-01';
```

This approach is clean, and also leaves the `WHERE` clause *sargable*, meaning that an index on `Date` can be used.  If you really want to stick with using `YEAR` and `MONTH`, then use:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Number1 - Number2) AS TOTAL 
FROM myTable 
WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2019 OR YEAR(Date) = 2020 AND MONTH(Date) = 1;
```